# GtkCellRendererToggle - color of toggle button inside treeview

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

I have a treeview that uses GtkCellRendererToggle to display toggle buttons inside cells. My question: Is is possible to set the color just for the toggle button there? I only know how to set the cell background, which is done like this:

```
g_object_set (toggle-renderer, "cell-background", 
              "anycolouryoulike", "cell-background-set", TRUE, NULL);
```

GtkCellRenderer features only cell background properties, I wonder if there is nethertheless a way to do it? (I use C, but if there is a way, an example in any language would do).

Answer (score 0):

GtkCssProvider might help, just try to style buttons within [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) ([list of suported properties per widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtkstylecontext-classes) , not necessary for this case)

You could use something like

```
#supercolorme {
    color: #ffed00;
}
```

and name your widgets `supercolorme` by using
`void gtk_widget_set_name (GtkWidget *widget, const gchar *name);` as described in the [gtk+ API docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-name)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree that GtkCssProvider is probably the only way to achieve this (I forgot about this, since I haven't used it so far). I have to check if it is possible for toggle buttons inside a treeview, for "stand alone" toggle buttons this would probably be easier.

Comment: The g_object_set is just a dirty way of overwriting some suported properties, the above should work for all widgets labeled/named `supercolorme` no matter where you place them.